# in react native im trying to get a svg file from the api but it shows

Tags: react-native, svg

can anyone tell me how to fixed this issue please,,im trying to get svg images from the api but its not working shows this error...
shows this error

```
Error: Expected > (2:106). If this is valid SVG, it's probably a bug. Please raise an issue
```

//my code

```
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';
<SvgUri   resizeMode="contain"
 style={{
  width: 45,
  height: 45, 
}}    

  uri= {`${baseurl}/${imageUri}`}
/>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with full code? not clear much. however just check whether baseurl and imageuri has values

Answer (score 2):

Try using SvgCssUri instesd of Svguri